# BigQuery: Format ISO Date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, isodate

I'm trying to parse a timestamp which is in ISO Date 8601 format.

Example: `2021-04-10T14:11:00Z`

This information is stored inside a JSON object and for that reason I'm extracting that data as a string:

The format I'm looking for is a yy-MM-dd hh:mm format and for that I've tried the following

**SQL CODE**

```
SELECT document_id,
json_extract(data, '$.Pair') as pair, 
PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%y-%m-%d %H:%M', json_extract(data, '$.AlertTime')) as alerttime,
COUNT(document_id) as alert_count
FROM `tradingview-alerts-26eb8.alltables.TradingView_000_raw_latest` as alert_view
GROUP BY alerttime, document_id, pair
```

**Errors**

The code from above causes the following error:

> Failed to parse input string '"2021-04-10T03:17:00Z"

The reason for this is the **T** in the middle of the date, I believe,

In order to discard that I tried this change:

```
SUBSTR(json_extract(data, '$.AlertTime'), 1, 10))
```

But with that I'm getting an error on a different row:

> Failed to parse input string '"2021-04-1'

I'm wondering if it is because of how the date is being presented (year-month-date) the date not having 2 digits? such as 2021-04-01 instead of 2021-04-1.

However if I try with

```
SUBSTR(json_extract(data, '$.AlertTime'), 1, 11))
```

The error I'm getting is

> Failed to parse input string '"2021-04-10'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include those ISO symbols into format specifier as constants:

```
select parse_timestamp('%FT%TZ', '2021-04-12T17:38:10Z')

|           f0_           |
---------------------------
| 2021-04-12 17:38:10 UTC |
```

**UPD**: If you have fractional seconds, you can include optional milliseconds element `%E*S` instead of time element `%T`. For non-UTC timestamps there should also be timezone element: `%Ez`. So, the possible solution could be:

```
with a as (
    select '2021-04-12T20:44:06.95841Z' as ts_str union all
    select '2021-04-12T23:44:07.83738+03:00' union all
    select '2021-04-12T23:44:08+03:00'
)
select parse_timestamp('%FT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez', regexp_replace(ts_str, 'Z$', '+00:00')) as ts
from a

|               ts               |
|--------------------------------|
| 2021-04-12 20:44:06.958410 UTC |
| 2021-04-12 20:44:07.837380 UTC |
| 2021-04-12 20:44:08 UTC        |
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist, one question though is that I want to avoid showing anything beyond the minutes (no seconds or timezones) any particular change in order to achieve that?

Comment: Timestamp is a complete datatype which stores all parts regardless of your input. Data display is another task, so you can apply any format you need at your application side or in select with `format_timestamp`

Comment: Thanks, it works fine with a sample date but not when I try to applied to the data in my table for some reason..

Comment: @LuisAlbertoDelgadodelaFlo I've added more options, please check

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use timestamp => datetime func.

Like this

```
datetime(timestamp(2021-11-29T00:00:00.000Z))
```